# Upload FIle in OneDrive with python

Tags: python, onedrive

I've tried to upload a file in OneDrive with python but I can't do it.

Here is an example of my code

```
import adal
import json

AUTHORITY_URL = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{}'.format('TENANT-ID')
CLIENT_ID = 'Client ID'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'Client Secret'  
RESOURCE = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/'

context = adal.AuthenticationContext(AUTHORITY_URL)
token = context.acquire_token_with_client_credentials(RESOURCE, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)

print(json.dumps(token, indent=2))
#### To this pont its everithing ok, the code generates a token

import requests

# the url to upload the file direct to the root
url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children/Texto.txt/content"

# name of the file to be uploaded
file_path = "Texto.txt"

headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer " + token["accessToken"]}

# Open the txt file and try to put in One drive but i get <Response [400]> and nothing happend
with open(file_path, "rb") as f:
    content = f.read()

response = requests.put(url, data=content, headers=headers)

response
```

I think the fist par when the token is generate its ok, but I don't know woh to continue.

With print(response.text)

```
'{"error":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"/me request is only valid with delegated authentication flow.","innerError":{"date":"2023-01-11T16:20:30","request-id":"ed0baf5e-07fe-45cc-af3d-d688f11ee725","client-request-id":"ed0baf5e-07fe-45cc-af3d-d688f11ee725"}}}'
```

thanks for the help!!

Comment: What does the error response say?

Comment: Just says <Response [400]>

Comment: Do `print(response.text)`.

Comment: I added the result on the question

Comment: The failure is indicating that your token is most likely an "app-only" token (i.e. it has application permissions and not delegated permissions). In that case there's no user identity in the token and so the system cannot resolve the meaning of "me".